# nextLine method in Scanner class not accepting input (Java)

Tags: java, newline, java.util.scanner

Here's my code:

```
for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 5; arrayIndex++)
    {

        PhoneBookEntry PhoneBook = new PhoneBookEntry();
        System.out.println("Please enter a name");
        tempName = keyboard.nextLine();
        PhoneBook.setName(tempName);
        System.out.println("Please enter a corresponding phone number");
        tempNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        PhoneBook.setPhoneNum(tempNum);

        EntryList.add(PhoneBook);

    }
```

Apparently there is a problem with the nextLine method on the second try. How could I fix this? I am not allowed to use any class other than scanner for this.

Thanks

EDIT: The error it gives is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchEx
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at PhoneBookApp.main(PhoneBookApp.java:39)
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is... an error? an exception? unexpected behavior?  It's hard to answer your question without some details.

Comment: The error it gives is is an exception. I edited the question to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a `String` type for the phone numbers rather than an `int`. It would give you mismatch exceptions with certain numbers. In this instance using a `String` would be more appropriate.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a corresponding phone number");
String tempNum = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mixing and matching nextLine with nextInt is what caused the problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the first result on Google](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090103175947AA5pyjq) when googling "nextLine"